# How to make specific JS script work only for certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, jquery-mobile, cookies

How to make script for specific page, checking existing cookies and if exists redirecting to specified page? So far I have something like this, but it keeps triggering the function on every page for some reason( just to clarify I use jQueryMobile):

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
  jQuery(function($){
    if ($('body#home').length){
      if($.cookie('usr') && $.cookie('psw')){
        $.mobile.changePage("http://imes.**********.com/userpanel.php");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In future I won't be storing name and password in cookie, I know about security issues of this approach, I will be storing generated key to match user from user cookie, but for now, for stage of testing I use these cookies.

Comment: But... If you removed it from the pages where it should not be called, it won't be called right? So what's wrong with that approach? But your approach will only work with bodies that have the ID 'home', so that should have solved your problem too, unless all your pages' bodies have the ID 'home'. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: Well that's a thing, only one page have id so far, and its still triggering on every page.

Comment: That's not really possible...

Comment: I have it all, all my other scripts in one central .js file, not separately on pages, is it possible that might be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID approach is essentially good, but testing for the length is something I don't trust (I've got not arguments for that, just a feeling).

That's why I would go for this approach:

```
$("body#home").on("load", function() {
    // Eat your cookies here.
});
```

P.S.
Naming the tag is useless, it only takes time. The browser reads CSS selectors (and I think JS querySelectors too, then, PS is based on this assumption) from the right to the left, so it will first find the one element with the ID 'home', and then get all bodies (in this case there is only one body, but imagine you did `div#home` and had 100 divs on your page) and pick the right one. As every ID can only occur once on a page, it is not necessary to name the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what you are asking, but if you want to run code on a specific page only you can play around with `location.pathname` to determine what page you are on.

```
jQuery(function($){
    if ( location.pathname.indexOf( '/home' ) ){
        // ...
    }
});
```

This approach would be faster than having to look up dom nodes. Also, the username and password should be handled by sessions your backend language

Comment: That is usually what I do, I let php and sessions to take care of it, but this time I would like to make my whole web app "php free" and run everything through ajax, JSON, just JS.